# Fill in the number. Not as straight as it looks

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

The square below is missing a number:

[image: Fill in the number]

You have four options:

- 32
- 4
- 16
- 22

Please explain your answer.

HINT:

> Something to do with addition.

Comment: Did you mean to spoiler the hint?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following grid

> which uses 16 as the missing number
>
>  [image]
>
>   is magic as adding the letter count spelling the numbers is 21 horizontally, vertically, diagonally.

Comment: Great thinking as always @Tom.